# Remove anchor descendant of an element with a specific data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Maybe it's a stupid question but is there any way that I can remove a link for a specific data-id? (see picture):

[image]

I hope my question make sense!

Comment: I don't see a link. What link are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove anything from the DOM, you will need to use JavaScript.

**Native JavaScript**

In modern browsers you could use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) to select the element, and then remove it from the DOM. Something like this:

```
var elm = document.querySelectorAll("li[data-id='id-166'] a.go-link");
elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
```

*Notice the somewhat limited browser-support for querySelectorAll - IE8 and above*

**jQuery**

Using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it could be done somewhat shorter:

```
$("li[data-id='id-166'] a.go-link").remove();
```

Comment: thanks for your answers. Maybe this gives a better idea of the link I refer to: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2377767/Screen-Shot-2013-03-30-at-12.101.jpg

Comment: @SørenJepsen Updated my answer to something I believe should do it for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can't believe that it worked! You just saved me hours of work/reseaching!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try jQuery's [.removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

`$('li.one-third.column').removeAttr('data-id');`

Comment: Your selector would match a `<column>` element that is child of the list-item.